# How should I signal to Tastypie that I cannot create a resource?

Tags: tastypie

When I implement myself obj_create() in Tastypie, what is the correct way to fail (because I know for instance that some quotas are exceeded) ? I guess there is a standard exception to raise but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By raising the `ImmediateHttpResponse` exception with one of the `tastypie.http` `HttpResponse` (from Django) sub-classes.

```
from tastypie.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from tastypie.http import HttpSeeOther

...
    raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpSeeOther())
```